# Certificate validation failure for oracle anonymous cloud database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I am trying to run an HTTPS request which is
I was facing an issue with ACL privileges which I solved by running this proc

```
begin
dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl (
   acl          => 'networkacl.xml',
   description  => 'Allow Network Connectivity',
   principal    => 'PUBLIC',
   is_grant     => TRUE,
   privilege    => 'connect',
   start_date   => SYSTIMESTAMP,
   end_date     => NULL);

dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl (
   acl         => 'networkacl.xml',
   host        => '*',
   lower_port  => NULL,
   upper_port  => NULL);
commit;
end;
```

after running this I was able to request HTTPS URLs but when I am trying to access any URLs now
such as the below one

```
select utl_http.request('https://myappname.scm.azurewebsites.net') from dual;
```

I am getting this error

```
ORA-29024: Certificate validation failure
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 380
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1534
```

after reading some blogs on the internet I understood I need to get the certificate from the browser and need to add it to the wallet but the problem is I am using an Autonomous cloud database from oracle and everyone on the blog is talking about adding those cert locally so I am not sure where it needs to be added and I am even not sure whether I am on right track to solve this issue if anyone can guide me what needs to be done it would be great

Comment: Those kinds of configurations require access to the underlying operating system. You can't do that with Autonomous Database (note: _not_ Anonymous!).

Comment: In the [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/appendix-database-pl-sql-packages-restrictions.html#GUID-829A7D07-1EA4-4F59-AA60-F780FABAFDEC) you can read this:
Your instance is preconfigured with an Oracle Wallet that contains more than 90 of the most commonly trusted root and intermediate SSL certificates. This Oracle Wallet is centrally managed and therefore you cannot consume 3rd party web services that are protected using self-signed SSL certificates.
 So maybe your url is self-signed?

Comment: @gsalem I have deployed my webapi on azure and the url is been signed by azure itself

Comment: Then Ask Oracle (via support), if Azure is among the list they support (probably it is, but under some conditions).

Comment: @gsalem since I am using Autonomous oracle do not provide support for it and just to update even https://google.com is not working

Comment: Oracle surely provides support for autonomous, but you're using the free tier I suppose?

Comment: @gsalem I was able to solve the issue :D

Comment: Add your solution as an answer to help others who stumble across some issue.